# How to access offsetTop property of div in reactive variable?

Tags: javascript, dom, svelte, svelte-3

I have the following (simplified) structure:

```
DIV 1 (changing height because of an accordion)
–––--
DIV 2 (getting pushed down, offsetTop changing accordingly)
```

I want to assign offsetTop to a reactive variable in Svelte to be able to do calculations based on the current offsetTop of DIV 2.

What I have tried:

```
<script>
let mapContainer;
$: map_offset = mapContainer?.offsetTop;
</script>

<div id="div1">
<!-- more going on here -->
</div>
<div id="div2" bind:this={mapContainer}>
{map_offset}
</div>
```

I used optional chaining to prevent the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetTop')

I am not getting errors anymore and map_offset is populated with a value when the page loads, but it does not change when DIV 1 changes its height although I have checked that mapContainer.offsetTop has changed. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks perfectly fine and *should* work in my opinion. I would have written it the same way, and I cannot understand why the reactive statement does not run.

Hopefully someone else will come up with an explanation.

In the meantime, all I can offer is a workaround using `afterUpdate` which is a Svelte lifecycle function that gets called everytime the component is updated:

```js
<script>
import { afterUpdate } from 'svelte';

let mapContainer;
let map_offset; // needs to be declared if you comment out the reactive statement
// $: map_offset = mapContainer?.offsetTop;

afterUpdate(() => {
  map_offset = mapContainer.offsetTop;
});
</script>

<div id="div1">
<!-- more going on here -->
</div>
<div id="div2" bind:this={mapContainer}>
{map_offset}
</div>
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/9f2e348a8eae4cb9912e7c45e2b5d687?version=3.46.4)

Comment: This is the correct answer. Right now nothing in OP's state is changing to trigger the reactivity of the statement. The offsetTop change occurs in the DOM not in the state. So Svelte has no way of knowing anything has changed in that statement. Using afterUpdate reacts to changes in the DOM as opposed to state so you can explicitly tell the state about the changes in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation @JHeth. I would have thought that binding the element would bring along these DOM changes back into the state however?

Comment: I assume that would complicate Svelte's reactivity system quite a bit. In a situation like this where you're checking for offsetTop of an element you would also need to fire an event when the screen resizes to make sure the state knows about the shape of the DOM since resizing the window does not trigger `afterUpdate`. Or you could bind-to and add up the height of elements above the element and not worry about the DOM as much like in this REPL https://svelte.dev/repl/b61001a67332465ab1be6dcae4e1ebc3?version=3.46.4

Comment: Thank you! I also found out that afterUpdate does not work in my case and does not fire when the accordion expands. As a workaround I implemented a writable store to collect offsetHeight values of all components above my map (DIV 2). This way I can get the offsetTop by calculating the sum of all heights in a derived store. This works perfectly fine, but I would have expected to be able to come up with a much simpler and more elegant solution.